# Unable to figure out username and password for Sendgrid SMTP (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, environment-variables, sendgrid

I work on quite a large site and we recently had a big vulnerability that exposed our .env details. We've since changed all of our API keys, including Sendgrid.

The problem I have here is that we can't figure out what the correct scheme is for the MAIL_USERNAME and MAIL_PASSWORD variables.

The key they provide is something like this: `SG.<some characters>.<some characters>`

In the .env we had before, the MAIL_USERNAME was set to the first "some characters" and presumably the password was the second part although they don't allow us to view the API key.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.sendgrid.net
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=<first part of API key>
MAIL_PASSWORD=<second part of API key>
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Can anyone tell me if I'm doing something completely stupid here, or point me in the right direction?

Comment: Also just to clear up some things we've already tried: Using the login details as the username and password, generating new API keys and using different parts of the key for each variable

Comment: please try `php artisan config:clear` and check if you add sender email id at `config/mail.php`.

Comment: The mail from address/name and mail to stuff is all set up as well. So now I have got past the issue of setting the username and password as I figured out the credentials to use but still nothing is sending out. I'll update this as soon as I have more info.

Answer (score 6):

Since you're using [SMTP with your API Key](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Send/How_Emails_Are_Sent/api_keys.html#-Via-SMTP), your username should be the literal string `apikey`, and your password is the full API key, the whole `SG.*.*`.

Answer (score 3):

Modify the ***.env*** file as given below:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.sendgrid.net
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=apikey
MAIL_PASSWORD=SG.***.***
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_NAME="John Smith"
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=from@example.com
```

For details [click here](https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/laravel/).

For creating an API key [click here](https://sendgrid.com/docs/ui/account-and-settings/api-keys/).

Comment: where to find API key?